# Merge privada no github

Tags: github

Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma merge privada no github? Estou fazendo o backend de um pequeno projeto e só quero que os outros colaboradores tenham acesso assim que eu liberar essa merge. O repositório está registrado na minha conta.

Comment: Acredito que se você tornar o repositório privado (agora é possível usando a conta gratuita) e adicionando os colaboradores nas configurações do seu repositório, você consiga esse feito.

Comment: 1) Faça um *fork* privado; 2) Faça suas modificações; 3) Faça um *push* para o repositório público.